# Let Ubuntu server send an mail when system restart is required

Tags: updates, email

Is there a possibility that Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS can send a mail to specific email adresses when an update has been installed that require a server reboot

So for instance when the file /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs does exist that it sends a mail to the admins so they can reboot?

I have looked al over Google but cannot find an easy tutorial for this

Answer (score 1):

Try /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades

```
// Send email to this address for problems or packages upgrades
// If empty or unset then no email is sent, make sure that you
// have a working mail setup on your system. A package that provides
// 'mailx' must be installed. E.g. "user@example.com"
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "user@example.com";

// Set this value to "true" to get emails only on errors. Default
// is to always send a mail if Unattended-Upgrade::Mail is set
Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "false";
```

That's actually the easy part. Next, we must set up a lightweight postal system to get the e-mail off the server and over to you.

Here's one way to do that:

```
sudo apt install msmtp msmtp-mta bsd-mailx
```

Config file: `/root/.msmtprc`

```
account        your_label_here
host           smtp.example.com
port           465
from           root@your_machine.your_domain
user           user@example.com (your email)
password       your_smtp_password
auth           on
tls            on
tls_starttls   off
tls_certcheck  off
logfile        /root/.msmtp.log
account default : your_label_here
```

Test command:

```
echo "This is the email body" > /tmp/body.txt && sudo mailx -s "This is the subject" user@example.com < /tmp/body.txt; rm /tmp/body.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks I have followed the tutorial and edited a cronjob for this so infact as user root I have created the config file /root/.msmtprc

```
account        your_label_here
host           smtp.example.com
port           465
from           root@your_machine.your_domain
user           user@example.com (your email)
password       your_smtp_password
auth           on
tls            on
tls_starttls   off
tls_certcheck  off
logfile        /root/.msmtp.log
account default : your_label_here
```

Afterwards I created a file in /etc/cron.hourly/reboot-check

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
        echo "A reboot is required following updates to server <TestServer> the machine will auto reboot in 1h" > /tmp/body.txt && sudo mailx -s "Reboot Required" receivers@adress.com < /tmp/body.txt; rm /tmp/body.txt
fi
```

And when the machine has an update that requires a reboot and creates the /var/run/reboot-required file it sends me an email to notify me of the reboot

Comment: This is a duplicate of an existing answer.